# Get count of a certain value in a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have a situation where I have a dictionary (string key) storing a bunch of boolean configuration values. Now I've run into the issue that I need to count the number of True values in my dictionary, but I can't find an easy way to do it without just iterating through the dictionary with a loop.

These are the contents of my dictionary "Lights":

```
{"LivingRoom", False}
{"Kitchen", False}
{"Bedroom", True}
{"Porch", True}
{"Driveway", True}
```

So we can see that 3 lights are on, 2 lights are off. Let's say I want to tell the user how many lights are turned on. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test each value but you don't need to do it directly.

```
Dim trueCount = myDictionary.Count(Function(kvp) kvp.Value)
```

That `Count` is a LINQ extension method.  If you're not familiar with LINQ then a bit of general reading might be in order.  It is very useful for compressing loops into simple one-liners.  The equivalent non-LINQ would be:

```
Dim trueCount As Integer

For Each kvp In myDictionary
    If kvp.Value Then
        count += 1
    End If
Next
```

This LINQ would also work:

```
Dim trueCount = myDictionary.Values.Count(Function(b) b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm getting an error saying that "count has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed"

Comment: That means that `Count` is being interpreted as the `Dictionary.Count` property rather than the `Enumerable.Count` method, which means that you are missing the required assembly reference and/or namespace import. You need to have referenced the System.Core.dll assembly and imported (at either project or file level) the `System.Linq` namespace. You also need to be targeting .NET 3.5 or later, as that was when LINQ was first introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Under VB.net (4.8) `Dictionary.AsEnumerable().Count` instead of `Dictionary.Count` works without error or need of importing Linq-Namespace